# How can I display the number of rows in my tableview for my current viewcontroller in the cell.textLabel of the previous viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I am trying to design a workout log app and the functionality that I am aiming for is that the user can log each set by logging the weights and reps for that set, thereby creating a new row in the tableView every time. After they have logged all the sets therefore, the number of rows will be the number of sets.

I am using realm database so that each cell in the tableView links to a different property within a class.

The problem I am facing now is that I cannot figure out how to get the value of a specific property within a class, to be present in the viewController with which that class has a parent relationship.

I have tried creating a protocol and delegate but it can not get the specific value for each indexPath in the cell.

Any help would please be very much appreciated!

EDIT:

[Image of 'create new session' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnXCh.png)

[Image of 'log set' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mUM.png)

So the number of rows in the tableView on the 'log set' page corresponds to the number of sets. Each cell in the 'create new session' page segues to a different 'log set' page. I am trying to display how many rows are in the tableView that each cell segues too.

I can format my code for posting in later updates if what I am trying to accomplish is still unclear.

Comment: There's many ways to do this... The question as you've stated it seems a little too open-ended. Can you be more specific (for example, post your code)?

Comment: *so that each cell in the tableView links to a different property within a class* is quite unclear. Is your tableView displaying 1 set per row or something else? If it's 1 set per row then why link a cell to a property? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the question by adding some more pictures

Comment: Let me say this back; The Create New Session page has a list of sessions. When a user taps on a Session in the list, that segues to a child viewController (Log Set) which shows repetitions. From there's it's unclear; are you asking how to show the count of the number of reps in the Create New Session view? So it would be "Your seesion was on 31/03/2021 3" with 3 being the count of rows from the Log Set view? If so, you can just get the count of repetitions from the same dataSource you use to populate the Log Set tableVIew from. let reps = dataSource.count

Comment: Ahhhhhh I feel so dumb! Thank you very much, dataSource.count was exactly what I needed! I got too caught up and got overcomplicated trying to save the number of rows as a separate property in a realm class and then trying to load it in the previous view controller... But your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your time and help responding to a complete random post on stack overflow! I'm very new to coding so didn't think anyone would really see this!

Comment: Glad I could help! Going forward be sure to add code and structures as text and if you need to include an image, include it in the actual question. Links break and if that were to happen we would not understand the question. You can't add images yet because you're new but after you get enough rep, you can. Also, when responding in comments preface the person name with an at sign. Like @Jay